# Taking the left side of an image in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on the MNIST data set, and I want to take the left side of an image.
Each image in the test data set is represented as a numpy array of 784 (28X28) elements (gray levels in the range [0,1]).
So ,for example, if I want to take the top side:

```
img=test[0][0] #img is now a numpy array of 784 elements
top_side=img[:784/2]
top_side=top_side.reshape([14,28]) #turning the vector to the image shape
```

But I can't figure out how to take the left side of the image from the vector.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reshape` first to get the full image and then take the slice for the left
image:

```
full_image=img.reshape([28,28])
left_side = full_image[:,:14]
```

This technique works also for all other sub-images.